# Syntax error: unexpected end of file, when sourcing .bashrc, even with brand new known working file

Tags: bash

The title sums up the problem. I accidentally added a script that echoed aliases into bashrc, to the end of it and sourced it. This changed something so that now any file I try to source (I tried .profile also) returns this error. I'm trying to figure out what happened to prevent it in the future. I've copied the text from a known working default bashrc file and it still does the same thing. Very unusual.. I feel like it somehow injected something into the code that does the sourcing, or set some setting or variable to have an unclosed bracket or something, or a formatting setting.

Does anyone know the mechanism that source uses? Or have any idea what to check or how that could happen? Or maybe how to source the file in an alternate way?

A related question that doesn't solve my issue:
[Syntax Error: unexpected end of file — Bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193165/syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-bash-script)

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    #alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

I narrowed it down to this section. But it still errors with the section below it uncommented. I'm using the goto command `: <<'END'.....END` for block commenting.

```
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
```

It appears any code block with if statements causes the error. Progress! ..I've narrowed it down to this minimal if statement causes it:

```
if [ false ] ; then a=0
fi
```

When I enter `if [ false ] ; then echo hi; fi` on the shell, I get a set of > new lines, like it is waiting for me to finish with an ending quote or brace.

Comment: Please include the offending files in your question. Format them as code with the `{}` button. Shortening the files is acceptable - and even encouraged - provided that the resulting files still trigger the issue

Comment: And if the file is too long to post, remove the unrelated parts. You'll know them, since they'll be the ones that _don't_ change the result when removed. If removing some part removes the issue, then the problem is with that part. (And then you can either just leave it off and be done, or post it here and get help in figuring out why it caused the problem.)

Comment: @roaima, thank you.. I was under the assumption that any file would, even a blank.. which I just tested, and even the first few lines work.. so I can start narrowing in to which part is problematic. I'll post the file above as well.

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks.. I added a comment and am testing different sections now. It must be another function or file inside that it is referencing.. one that is also in .profile

Comment: @alchemy note that on some distributions, the default `~/.profile` itself sources `~/.bashrc` when it detects that the shell is bash

Comment: @steeldriver, ah, that makes sense ;) I've tracked it down to the if statements. Even a minimal one will error.

Comment: You haven't by any chance created an alias named `fi` have you?

Comment: @steeldriver, that's where I just looked and yes, I set 'fi' to find.. I'm surprised it would override a builtin like that.. I didnt think to check for a conflict. ...aliasing back to 'fi' removes the error. Thanks all of you! I'm also a bit surprised that sourcing a fresh .bashrc and even rebooting didnt remove the alias. It must be stored in another user's bashrc too.

Comment: @steeldriver, I had a made up a list of aliases for the most common commands I use to help beginners and myself remember and organized them. I did have it loaded in to my root .bashrc as well, so the source command must be using the root's aliases. I backed out to the normal user to troubleshoot when things went amiss.

Comment: fwiw, the list of aliases is an alphabetical mnemonic with only a single letter or two and as few commands per letter. ..also 'fi' turns out not to be one of the builtins `compgen -b`

Comment: @alchemy, aliases are weird. Unlike basically everything else, they're just text replacement, done really early in the command line processing. Apparently in Bash and zsh, it means you can break the shell syntax like that with them. Not all shells though, Dash and ksh don't let the `fi` alias break like that.